# EventKit + Swift: Get Events

Tags: swift, eventkit

I am trying to use EventKit to read the user's current events for the day and am having some trouble.

To make it easier, I tried using [TTEventKit](https://github.com/tattn/TTEventKit) for wrapping, but still without success.   Here's my current code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    EventStore.requestAccess() { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("got permission")
        }
    }


    let events = EventStore.getEvents(Month(year: 2016, month: 7))

    if events != nil {
        for e in events {
            print("Title \(e.title)")
            print("startDate: \(e.startDate)")
            print("endDate: \(e.endDate)")

    }

}
}
```

The code above is printing the events, but there are a few things that aren't working:

- it won't accept `NSDate` for `getevents` and
- it is only getting the events from a generic calendar (just showing like US holidays).

How can I fix these two issues?